# Are these two binary logic expressions equal?

Tags: c, binary

Given the question:

> Write C expressions, in terms of variable x, for the following values.
>   Your code should work for any word size w ≥ 8. For reference, we show
>   the result of evaluating the expressions for x = 0x87654321, with w =
>   32.
>
> B. All but the least significant byte of x complemented, with the
>   least significant byte left unchanged. [0x789ABC21].

I came up with the solution:

`(~x)^0xFF` but the provided solution was: `x ^ ~0xFF` - are these equivalent expressions?

Comment: I can give a hint: if the boolean expressions ~x ^ y and x ^ ~y are equivalent, then the answer to your question is yes. Since x and y can only have two values each, you can solve it with a truth table.

Comment: @mzedeler  `~x` works on the size of `x` or `int`, which every is wider.  `~0xFF` only flips bits on an `int`.

Comment: So ~0xFF == 0, leaving x ^ ~0xFF an a no-op whereas (~x)^0xFF will flip the lowest 8 bytes of ~x. Thanks, @chux.

Comment: @mzedeler Not`~0xFF == 0`  but --> `0xFF00` if `int` 16-bit (smallest possible),  --> `0xFFFFFF00` if `int` 32-bit,  --> `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00` if `int` 64-bit, etc.  It depends on `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are not always equivalent, and your solution is far better:

`(~x) ^ 0xFF` complements `x` for all integer types and restores the low order byte.

`x ^ ~0xFF` is more tricky: `~0xFF` will be computed as an `int` and then extended to the type of `x` before xoring.  It may not work as expected if `x` is an integer type larger than `int` and the representation of `int` is sign+magnitude.

Indeed, the following code:

```
unsigned long x = 12345678;
x = x ^ ~0xFF;
```

Produces the following warning with `clang -Weverything`:

```
xxo.c:4:13: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-conversion]
x = x ^ ~0xFF;
      ~ ^~~~~
```

Furthermore, note that neither expression is correct if the size of `w` is smaller than the size of `int`.  Say for example that `int` is 32 bits and `short` is 16 bits:

```
unsigned short x = 0x4321;
```

The expected result should be `0xBC21`, but:

```
x ^ ~0xFF  ->  0x4321 ^ 0xFFFFFF00  ->  0xFFFFBC21
```

and

```
(~x) ^ 0xFF  ->  0xFFFFBCEF ^ 0xFF  ->  0xFFFFBC21
```

To fix this issue, the expression should be cast to the type of `x`, preferably an unsigned type.

Finally, note that you can shorten the expression this way:  `0xFF ^ ~x`

Comment: Yes `(~x)^0xFF` meets "code should work for any word size w ≥ 8".  `x ^ ~0xFF` does not.  Good eye.

Comment: @chux: I'm afraid this simple question is actually more subtle than I first thought.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

And you can leave out (). ~ takes precedence over ^  ... and even if it didnt ( like ~(x^0xFF) ) you would still get the same result ...

Ain't that funny ?

Answer (score 0):

1. XOR is a symmetric binary operator. Therefore where lies the `~` is irrelevant.
2. just a thinking pattern: take a sampled bit from `x` and track down its value:
   on our left expression every 1-bit becomes due to negation 0-bit and then 1-bit again after XORing with `0xFF` constant. 0-bit for same reasons becomes 0-bits.
   on our right expression we happen to XOR `x` with 0 value in each bit. from XOR binary table it is easy to see that each bit in x will remain the same: 1-bits stays the same and 0-bits stays the same. And there you have it, expressions yield the same results.
   long road for simple answer...